# How to save a chosen number of coordinates along the path in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I would like to save coordinates along the path to further morph them and produce several more paths. Currently, I have a solution based on `decorations.markings` which seems to be almost working, yet so far only the coordinate counter is being incremented instead.

Here is the current picture produced:

[image]

The path along which I attempt to save coordinates starts at the top of the upper circle inside the circle representing [image: X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3] and ends on the circle representing [image] (the image of the corresponding function).

The full source code will be provided in the end of the question.

There on lines 11 through 30 you can find the declaration and initialization of the coordinate counter and the `tikzset`s with `style`s and `code`s that are desired to save the coordinates. For convenience, I will duplicate them here:

```tex
        \newcounter{coordinateindex}
        \setcounter{coordinateindex}{0}
 
        \tikzset{
            stepcounter/.code={
                \stepcounter{coordinateindex}
            }
        }
 
        \tikzset{
            save coordinates/.style={
                decoration={markings,
                    mark=at position 0 with { \coordinate (coordinate\thecoordinateindex); },
                    mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.1 with {
                        \coordinate[preaction=stepcounter] (coordinate\thecoordinateindex);
                    }
                },
                postaction={decorate}
            }
        }
```

You can ignore the fact that the first coordinate is saved twice.

On line 159 the `save coordinates` `style` is applied to the path:

```tex
\draw[L1,very thick,save coordinates] (FarEndX1) arc[start angle=180,end angle=160,x radius=100, y radius = 10] coordinate(Img1);
```

Once again, how do I save a chosen number of coordinates along the path in Tikz? I did not find an answer in the Tikz&PGF manual for Version 3.1.9.a.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcounter{coordinateindex}
        \setcounter{coordinateindex}{0}
 
        \tikzset{
            stepcounter/.code={
                \stepcounter{coordinateindex}
            }
        }
 
        \tikzset{
            save coordinates/.style={
                decoration={markings,
                    mark=at position 0 with { \coordinate (coordinate\thecoordinateindex); },
                    mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.1 with {
                        \coordinate[preaction=stepcounter] (coordinate\thecoordinateindex);
                    }
                },
                postaction={decorate}
            }
        }
 
        \definecolor{L1}{HTML}{ECD9ED}
        \definecolor{L2}{HTML}{C7DAC4}
        \definecolor{L3}{HTML}{E4B1AD}
        \definecolor{L1L2}{HTML}{EF3A43}
        \definecolor{L1L3}{HTML}{B7CA54}
        \definecolor{L2L3}{HTML}{4C4B6B}
        \definecolor{L1L2L3}{HTML}{FBC405}      
 
        \newlength{\smallradius}    
        \setlength{\smallradius}{1cm}
 
        \coordinate (X1) at (0.5,0.75);
        \newcommand{\uppercircle}{(X1) circle(\smallradius)};
        \path [name path=upper circle] \uppercircle;
 
        \coordinate(X2) at (0,0);
        \newcommand{\leftlowercircle}{(X2) circle(\smallradius)};
        \path [name path=left lower circle] \leftlowercircle;
 
        \coordinate(X3) at (1,0);
        \newcommand{\rightlowercircle}{(X3) circle(\smallradius)};
        \path [name path=right lower circle] \rightlowercircle;
 
        % Point of median (X1--Mx1) in the triangle (X1--X2--X3) on the side (X2--X3)
        \coordinate (Mx1) at ($(X2)!.5!(X3)$);
        \path [name path= median x1] (X1)--(Mx1);
 
        % Point of median (X2--Mx2) in the triangle (X1--X2--X3) on the side (X1--X3)
        \coordinate (Mx2) at ($(X1)!.5!(X3)$);
        \path [name path= median x2] (X2)--(Mx2);
 
        % Point of median (X3--Mx3) in the triangle (X1--X2--X3) on the side (X1--X2)
        \coordinate (Mx3) at ($(X1)!.5!(X2)$);
        \path [name path= median x3] (X3)--(Mx3);
 
        % Centroid of the triangle (X1--X2--X3) and, more importantly, the center of the circumscribed circle of the circles (X1,1), (X2,1), and (X3,1)
        \path [name intersections={of=median x1 and median x2,by=X1X2X3}];
        \newlength{\bigradius}
        \newlength{\bigdiameter}        
        \setlength{\bigradius}{2cm}
        \setlength{\bigdiameter}{2\bigradius}
 
        % Line width options: "line width=<dimension>", and abbreviations "ultra thin" for 0.1pt, "very thin" for 0.2pt, "thin" for 0.4pt (the default width), "semithick" for 0.6pt, "thick" for 0.8pt, "very thick" for 1.2pt, "ultra thick" for 1.6pt.
        \newlength{\contourthickness}
        \setlength{\contourthickness}{1.2pt}
 
        \newcommand{\boundingbox}{($(X1X2X3) - (\bigradius,\bigradius)$) rectangle ($(X1X2X3) + (\bigradius,\bigradius)$)}
 
        \path [name intersections={of=upper circle and left lower circle,by={FarEndX1X2,LowerRightEndX1X2X3}}];
        \path [name intersections={of=upper circle and right lower circle,by={FarEndX1X3,LowerLeftEndX1X2X3}}];
        \path [name intersections={of=left lower circle and right lower circle,by={UpperEndX1X2X3,FarEndX2X3}}];        
 
        \coordinate(FarEndX1) at ($(X1)-(Mx1)+(Mx1)!\smallradius!(X1X2X3)$);
        \coordinate(FarEndX1LeftContourStart) at ($(FarEndX1)-(X1X2X3)+(X1X2X3)!\contourthickness!90:(FarEndX1)$);
        \coordinate(FarEndX1RightContourStart) at ($(FarEndX1)-(X1X2X3)+(X1X2X3)!\contourthickness!270:(FarEndX1)$);
 
        \coordinate(FarEndX2) at ($(X2)-(Mx2)+(Mx2)!\smallradius!(X1X2X3)$);
 
        \coordinate(FarEndX3) at ($(X3)-(Mx3)+(Mx3)!\smallradius!(X1X2X3)$);
 
        % Upper greater petal
        \scope
            \clip \boundingbox
                \leftlowercircle
                \rightlowercircle;
            \fill[color=L1] \uppercircle;
        \endscope
 
        % Left greater petal
        \scope
            \clip \boundingbox
                \uppercircle
                \rightlowercircle;
            \fill[color=L2] \leftlowercircle;
        \endscope
 
        % Right greater petal
        \scope
            \clip \boundingbox
                \uppercircle
                \leftlowercircle;
            \fill[color=L3] \rightlowercircle;
        \endscope
 
        % Left smaller petal
        \scope
            \clip \boundingbox
                \rightlowercircle;
            \clip \leftlowercircle;
            \fill[color=L1L2] \uppercircle;
        \endscope
 
        % Right smaller petal
        \scope
            \clip \boundingbox
                \leftlowercircle;
            \clip \uppercircle;
            \fill[color=L1L3] \rightlowercircle;
        \endscope
 
        % Lower smaller petal
        \scope
            \clip \boundingbox
                \uppercircle;
            \clip \leftlowercircle;
            \fill[color=L2L3] \rightlowercircle;
        \endscope
 
        % Center
        \scope
            \clip \uppercircle;
            \clip \leftlowercircle;
            \clip \rightlowercircle;
            \fill[color=L1L2L3] \boundingbox;
        \endscope
 
        % outline
        \draw \uppercircle
            \leftlowercircle
            \rightlowercircle;              
 
        \node[draw, circle, minimum size= \bigdiameter, label=below:$X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3$] at  (X1X2X3) {};
 
        % Solutions from upper greater petal
        % TODO: consider using loop since FarEndX1LeftContourStart and FarEndX1RightContourStart are intersections of circles (X1,1) and (FarEndX1, delta)
        \draw[black,very thin] (FarEndX1LeftContourStart) arc[start angle=180,end angle=160,x radius=100, y radius = 10];
        \draw[black,very thin] (FarEndX1RightContourStart) arc[start angle=180,end angle=160,x radius=100, y radius = 10];
        \draw[L1,very thick,save coordinates] (FarEndX1) arc[start angle=180,end angle=160,x radius=100, y radius = 10] coordinate(Img1);
 
        % Image (as in set theory) of the first function
        \fill[color=white] (Img1) circle (1);
        \node[draw, circle, color=black, minimum size=2cm, label=below:{$[(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto x_1-2x_2-x_3]^{\rightarrow}$} ] at (Img1) {};
        \draw[fill] (FarEndX2) circle[radius=2pt];
        \draw[fill] (FarEndX3) circle[radius=2pt];
        \draw[fill] (UpperEndX1X2X3) circle[radius=2pt];
        \draw[fill] (LowerLeftEndX1X2X3) circle[radius=2pt];
        %\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\thecoordinateindex}
        %   \draw[fill] (coordinate\i) circle[radius=2pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not link to code on external websites, but provide a MWE directly in your question. Otherwise parts of the question might not be readable/accessible anymore for future readers.

Comment: I'll fix it in a moment!

Comment: @epR8GaYuh Done! Sorry for breaking the rules.

Comment: Instead of `\coordinate[preaction=stepcounter] ...`, try `\coordinate[stepcounter] ...`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit As I stated in the question, you can ignore the fact that the coordinate is saved twice. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Comment: In your case, the `/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number` key (p. 648, pgfmanual v3.1.9a) can be useful...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Let me take a look

Comment: @PaulGaborit I chose the counter version because the alternative was quite mouthful (=overly verbose). However, I will check it because it might solve the problem.

Comment: The solution to changing your current code as little as possible is just to not use `preaction`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126747/discussion-between-dmitrii-demenev-and-paul-gaborit).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(Note: when you write `\coordinate[preaction=stepcounter] ...`, the `preaction` key is not used at all. So the `stepcounter` code is not called.)*

Instead of `\coordinate[preaction=stepcounter]...`, use `\coordinate[stepcounter]...`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcounter{coordinateindex}
  \setcounter{coordinateindex}{0}
  
  \tikzset{
    stepcounter/.code={
      \stepcounter{coordinateindex}
    }
  }
  
  \tikzset{
    save coordinates/.style={
      decoration={markings,
        mark=at position 0 with { \coordinate (coordinate\thecoordinateindex); },
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.1 with {
          \coordinate[stepcounter] (coordinate\thecoordinateindex);
        }
      },
      postaction={decorate}
    }
  }

  
  \definecolor{L1}{HTML}{ECD9ED}
  \definecolor{L2}{HTML}{C7DAC4}
  \definecolor{L3}{HTML}{E4B1AD}
  \definecolor{L1L2}{HTML}{EF3A43}
  \definecolor{L1L3}{HTML}{B7CA54}
  \definecolor{L2L3}{HTML}{4C4B6B}
  \definecolor{L1L2L3}{HTML}{FBC405}              
  
  \newlength{\smallradius}        
  \setlength{\smallradius}{1cm}
  
  \coordinate (X1) at (0.5,0.75);
  \newcommand{\uppercircle}{(X1) circle(\smallradius)};
  \path [name path=upper circle] \uppercircle;
  
  \coordinate(X2) at (0,0);
  \newcommand{\leftlowercircle}{(X2) circle(\smallradius)};
  \path [name path=left lower circle] \leftlowercircle;
  
  \coordinate(X3) at (1,0);
  \newcommand{\rightlowercircle}{(X3) circle(\smallradius)};
  \path [name path=right lower circle] \rightlowercircle;
  
  % Point of median (X1--Mx1) in the triangle (X1--X2--X3) on the side (X2--X3)
  \coordinate (Mx1) at ($(X2)!.5!(X3)$);
  \path [name path= median x1] (X1)--(Mx1);
  
  % Point of median (X2--Mx2) in the triangle (X1--X2--X3) on the side (X1--X3)
  \coordinate (Mx2) at ($(X1)!.5!(X3)$);
  \path [name path= median x2] (X2)--(Mx2);
  
  % Point of median (X3--Mx3) in the triangle (X1--X2--X3) on the side (X1--X2)
  \coordinate (Mx3) at ($(X1)!.5!(X2)$);
  \path [name path= median x3] (X3)--(Mx3);
  
  % Centroid of the triangle (X1--X2--X3) and, more importantly, the center of the circumscribed circle of the circles (X1,1), (X2,1), and (X3,1)
  \path [name intersections={of=median x1 and median x2,by=X1X2X3}];
  \newlength{\bigradius}
  \newlength{\bigdiameter}                
  \setlength{\bigradius}{2cm}
  \setlength{\bigdiameter}{2\bigradius}
  
  % Line width options: "line width=<dimension>", and abbreviations "ultra thin" for 0.1pt, "very thin" for 0.2pt, "thin" for 0.4pt (the default width), "semithick" for 0.6pt, "thick" for 0.8pt, "very thick" for 1.2pt, "ultra thick" for 1.6pt.
  \newlength{\contourthickness}
  \setlength{\contourthickness}{1.2pt}
  
  \newcommand{\boundingbox}{($(X1X2X3) - (\bigradius,\bigradius)$) rectangle ($(X1X2X3) + (\bigradius,\bigradius)$)}
  
  \path [name intersections={of=upper circle and left lower circle,by={FarEndX1X2,LowerRightEndX1X2X3}}];
  \path [name intersections={of=upper circle and right lower circle,by={FarEndX1X3,LowerLeftEndX1X2X3}}];
  \path [name intersections={of=left lower circle and right lower circle,by={UpperEndX1X2X3,FarEndX2X3}}];                
  
  \coordinate(FarEndX1) at ($(X1)-(Mx1)+(Mx1)!\smallradius!(X1X2X3)$);
  \coordinate(FarEndX1LeftContourStart) at ($(FarEndX1)-(X1X2X3)+(X1X2X3)!\contourthickness!90:(FarEndX1)$);
  \coordinate(FarEndX1RightContourStart) at ($(FarEndX1)-(X1X2X3)+(X1X2X3)!\contourthickness!270:(FarEndX1)$);
  
  \coordinate(FarEndX2) at ($(X2)-(Mx2)+(Mx2)!\smallradius!(X1X2X3)$);
  
  \coordinate(FarEndX3) at ($(X3)-(Mx3)+(Mx3)!\smallradius!(X1X2X3)$);
  
  % Upper greater petal
  \scope
  \clip \boundingbox
  \leftlowercircle
  \rightlowercircle;
  \fill[color=L1] \uppercircle;
  \endscope
  
  % Left greater petal
  \scope
  \clip \boundingbox
  \uppercircle
  \rightlowercircle;
  \fill[color=L2] \leftlowercircle;
  \endscope
  
  % Right greater petal
  \scope
  \clip \boundingbox
  \uppercircle
  \leftlowercircle;
  \fill[color=L3] \rightlowercircle;
  \endscope
  
  % Left smaller petal
  \scope
  \clip \boundingbox
  \rightlowercircle;
  \clip \leftlowercircle;
  \fill[color=L1L2] \uppercircle;
  \endscope
  
  % Right smaller petal
  \scope
  \clip \boundingbox
  \leftlowercircle;
  \clip \uppercircle;
  \fill[color=L1L3] \rightlowercircle;
  \endscope
  
  % Lower smaller petal
  \scope
  \clip \boundingbox
  \uppercircle;
  \clip \leftlowercircle;
  \fill[color=L2L3] \rightlowercircle;
  \endscope
  
  % Center
  \scope
  \clip \uppercircle;
  \clip \leftlowercircle;
  \clip \rightlowercircle;
  \fill[color=L1L2L3] \boundingbox;
  \endscope
  
  % outline
  \draw \uppercircle
  \leftlowercircle
  \rightlowercircle;                      
  
  \node[draw, circle, minimum size= \bigdiameter, label=below:$X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3$] at  (X1X2X3) {};
  
  % Solutions from upper greater petal
  % TODO: consider using loop since FarEndX1LeftContourStart and FarEndX1RightContourStart are intersections of circles (X1,1) and (FarEndX1, delta)
  \draw[black,very thin] (FarEndX1LeftContourStart) arc[start angle=180,end angle=160,x radius=100, y radius = 10];
  \draw[black,very thin] (FarEndX1RightContourStart) arc[start angle=180,end angle=160,x radius=100, y radius = 10];
  \draw[L1,very thick,save coordinates] (FarEndX1) arc[start angle=180,end angle=160,x radius=100, y radius = 10] coordinate(Img1);
  
  % Image (as in set theory) of the first function
  \fill[color=white] (Img1) circle (1);
  \node[draw, circle, color=black, minimum size=2cm, label=below:{$[(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto x_1-2x_2-x_3]^{\rightarrow}$} ] at (Img1) {};
  \draw[fill] (FarEndX2) circle[radius=2pt];
  \draw[fill] (FarEndX3) circle[radius=2pt];
  \draw[fill] (UpperEndX1X2X3) circle[radius=2pt];
  \draw[fill] (LowerLeftEndX1X2X3) circle[radius=2pt];
  
  \foreach \i in {1,2,...,\thecoordinateindex}
  \draw[fill] (coordinate\i) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]